# Dynamically add to the model's Meta class?

Tags: django, django-models

Normally, you specify a table name for your model by putting in the model class:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'desired_tablename'
```

I want to add the table names for all my models dynamically at the end of models.py.
Can this be done in Django? If yes, how?

Comment: The real question is why would you want to do that?

Comment: Next time maybe ask the question before voting down.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this can be done simply like this:

```
MyModel._meta.db_table = 'desired_tablename'
```